# Why do some brokers allow selling naked put options but not naked call options?

Tags: options, brokerage

I understand that holding short positions in naked options is risky because they are not backed by cash or stock in a brokerage account. I've noticed that some brokers allow the selling of naked puts but not naked calls. Why is that?

Comment: It's simply because one can do "infinitely" badly; the other has a limit on how bad it can get.

Comment: **I understand that holding short positions in naked options is risky because they are not backed by cash or stock in a brokerage account.**  That statement is completely wrong.  Naked options have a Reg T margin requirement that *requires** that the trader maintain with cash or marginable securities.

Comment: @BobBaerker How much cash or marginable securities?

Comment: it depends on what the underlying is.  Google "CBOE Margin Manual"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A stock can only lose ~100% of its value on the downside, so while the risk is high it is effectively capped and definable selling naked puts as you can't go lower than zero on equities. Selling naked calls opens you to potential infinite risk as stocks can easily rise 100s (if not 1000s in some case) of percent higher from where they currently are.

Compare the risk profile of selling the INO $10 call with potentially infinite max risk:
[image]

With the risk profile of selling the $10 put, where you have a clear and definable max risk if the stock goes to zero:
[image]

If you're a broker the naked put sellers are as a result easier to work with in terms of risk modelling due to this cap on losses.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 levels of option trading approval:

- Level 1 – Covered Calls & Cash-Secured Puts
- Level 2 – Long Options
- Level 3 – Option Spreads
- Level 4 – Naked Calls & Puts

Because a naked call has the potential for  greater loss than a naked put, some brokers split  Level 4 above into two levels:

Level 4 – Naked short puts

Level 5 – Naked short calls

Comment: Where do these "levels" come from? Are these levels specified by a specific regulatory authority?

Comment: I would assume that it's a brokerage industry requirement since there is some variation at the upper levels (4 levels versus 5 levels)  although the [SEC](https://www.sec.gov/oiea/investor-alerts-bulletins/ib_openingoptionsaccount.html) does make mention of them.

Comment: The [SEC](https://www.sec.gov/oiea/investor-alerts-bulletins/ib_openingoptionsaccount.html) page you linked to contains the answer: "Broker-dealers generally offer 5 levels of option trading representing varying degrees of risk.  Level 1 generally represents the lowest level of risk, while level 5 generally represents the highest level of risk.  The types of option trading that occurs at each level and even the number of levels may vary among brokerage firms."

Comment: This is circular logic; the question is asking why the various strategies are assigned relative levels of risk.

Comment: Circular logic?  LOL.  The strategies allowed in each level have a defined amount of  of risk.  The higher the risk of the strategy, the higher the level of approval required. The only variance in the levels is whether a broker uses 4 levels or 5 levels.  The ones that use 5 levels are just  splitting naked options into two levels of risk.

Comment: The SEC has only a very limited authority. I'm quite sure that it is effectively irrelevant for >95% of the world's population.

Comment: OK, SEC rules are effectively irrelevant for  >95% of the world's population. But what does that have to do with approval levels that  brokers have established for regulating what option strategies clients can trade in the USA?